# Conceptual structuralism and continuum hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, mathematical-philosophy, continuum-hypothesis

In Ferefman's paper 'Is the Continuum Hypothesis a definite mathematical problem?', he argues that within the philosophy of conceptual structuralism, the continuum hypothesis is not a definite mathematical problem.

However, Koellner wrote a response to this paper in his paper 'Feferman on the Indefiniteness of CH'. In this, he proposes that it is possible to reach the conclusion that the continuum hypothesis is a definite mathematical problem via conceptual structuralism though he presents no argument for it. Instead, he relates this to the views of Martin and Isaacson.

Does anyone know where I can find an argument that the continuum hypothesis is a definite mathematical problem by the view of a conceptual structuralist?

Comment: Feferman's paper (http://logic.harvard.edu/EFI_Feferman_IsCHdefinite.pdf) and Koellner's response (http://logic.harvard.edu/EFI_Feferman_comments.pdf) were both part of a workshop at Harvard, in , called "Exploring the Frontiers of Infinity," and other materials can be found at http://logic.harvard.edu/efi.php#material. As for conceptual structuralism, the paper "Godel's conceptual realism" (http://www.jstor.org/stable/1556750) might be relevant, but I'm not sure - I don't have a totally precise sense of what "conceptual structuralism" means.

Answer (score 11):

Koellner is probably referring to the paper

- Daniel Isaacson, *The reality of mathematics and the case of set theory*, in: Zsolt Novak and Andras Simonyi (eds), *Truth, Reference, and Realism*, Central European University Press, 2011. [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.7829/j.ctt128283)
  ([author pdf](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/77d5/049677ea2656e99286871f9a57efe27b4fff.pdf)).

Isaacson appeals to Kreisel's argument that the second-order categoricity of set theory makes the continuum hypothesis a definite problem.